# Log in as different user during PowerShell script, but keeping the script going on same console window

Tags: windows, powershell, script, azure

so I am using PowerShell to create a Menu to host all of my smaller scripts but there are a few that require elevated rights, which I do have. I'm also wanting the dev team to be able to use this so this script will log in using my admin credentials and run the script.

So I'm trying to connect to our QA Service Fabric Cluster, and then pause an application for 5 minutes. I already know how to do this, I have the code for it, but this is what requires elevated rights. I'm aware on how you can start a new powershell window with admin credentials but for what I'm trying to do, I would like for the admin rights only to come around when the devs hit a certain option in the window. Here is the base code, and I will supply the code that I've tried:

```
# Randomly generates a GUID for the OperationID parameter.
$Guid = [guid]::NewGuid()

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster hqqacluster -WindowsCredential
              
Start-ServiceFabricPartitionQuorumLoss -quorumLossMode AllReplicas -ServiceName fabric:/MyApplication/Data" -QuorumLossDurationInSeconds 300 `
-PartitionKindSingleton -OperationId $Guid -Verbose
```

So from here, I would like to elevate my rights, since the option to connect to the QA cluster has been selected, but I don't want to open another powershell instance. I want to keep the same console and just continue the script. I've tried:

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
$credential
```

AND

```
runas /user:domain\administrator
```

Tried using $env:USERPROFILE as well but I don't think I was using that correctly. This is what I tried.

```
$env:USERPROFILE
C:\Users\Administrator
.\Stop_SF_Service_QA.ps1 -ScriptBlock {$evn:USERPROFILE} -Username 'Administrator' -Password 'Password' -wait
```

None of these seem to keep the script going after trying to elevate rights. The script just comes back with 'Access is denied.' But when running:

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
start powershell -credential $credential
```

It runs perfectly fine. But of course, this is starting a new console window. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you wouldn't be provided with answer, there is good chance that youļl find some useful tips in [gsudo source code](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo) (or any similar project). Or maybe gsudo itself will suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local PS Session for this, since they run with a specific user's `credential` and always run elevated:

```sh
# create an admin user powershell session
$s = New-PSSession -Credential $credential

# interactive for console
New-PSSession -Credential $credential | Enter-PSSession
# can now run admin commands as other user
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\AdminUser\Documents> Restart-Service -DisplayName 'Windows Update'  ## succeeds

# non-interactive for scripts:
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Restart-Service -DisplayName 'Windows Update'}
```

---

Note that this will behave like Remote sessions, which have some limitations. Make sure you look through some of the overviews on the topic:

- [PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/08-powershell-remoting)
- [About_remote_troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting)

For example, PS sessions are not allowed to forward windows credentials to a *second hop* without some additional configuration (`Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -WindowsCredential` will fail if run inside a session)

---

On a separate note, do **not** put plain text credentials in scripts - especially your admin credentials! You'll be better off giving the dev users permission to do what they need, or separate accounts.

If they only need to stop/start a service (just a guess based on the script name), then you could [grant that permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/grant-users-rights-manage-services) to the dev users, for example. Running as another user should only be done if that user also belongs to the person (or service) running the script. /soapbox